# static link undefined reference (CMAKE/MinGW)

Tags: c++, mingw, static-linking

I'm trying to build example MathGL project using MinGW with static link.
I have built Zlib and PNGlib as static libs (Zlib is static by default i think and removed 'shared-install' rule from PNGlib makefile) and got libz.a and libpng.a files in my C:/mingw32/lib.

MathGL provides CMAKE file, which cannot find theese libs, so I ran cmake with ZLIB_LIBRARY= and so on, successfully built it.

As a result, I have 3 files:

- libmgl.dll
- libmgl.dll.a
- libmgl.a

And compile example: `g++ main.cpp -IC:/mingw32/include -LC:/mingw32/lib -lmgl`
It works, but requires all mingw .dlls and libmgl.dll

If I provide the previous command with `-static`, I'm getting errors:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -IC:/mingw32/include -static -LC:/mingw32/lib -lmgl
C:\Users\stjfk\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyoT7RU.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8mglGraphC1Eiii[__ZN8mglGraphC1Eiii]+0xa): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV8mglGraph'
C:\Users\stjfk\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyoT7RU.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8mglGraphC1Eiii[__ZN8mglGraphC1Eiii]+0x2f): undefined reference to `_imp__mgl_create_graph_gl'
C:\Users\stjfk\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyoT7RU.o:main.cpp(.text$_ZN8mglGraphC1Eiii[__ZN8mglGraphC1Eiii]+0x4d): undefined reference to `_imp__mgl_create_graph'
C:\Users\stjfk\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyoT7RU.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8mglGraphD1Ev[__ZN8mglGraphD1Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV8mglGraph'
C:\Users\stjfk\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyoT7RU.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8mglGraphD1Ev[__ZN8mglGraphD1Ev]+0x28): undefined reference to `_imp__mgl_use_graph'
...
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why can't I link all libraries static? Does .a files mean static libs?

Comment: There are two types of libraries, `import` and `static`.  Exactly what type of libraries were you given?  An `import` library contains only "stubs" to the functions you're calling (usually the actual functions are implemented in DLL's).  A static library contains the actual code to the function you're calling.  So which is it?  The error suggests that you are compiling assuming an `import` library (the `_imp__` prefix indicates this).

Comment: Paul, I think you're right, but what dll.a files stand for? I thought it is import libs and .a are static. The same error if i provide .a file directly to g++.

Comment: Don't worry about the DLL.  Build the application.  When the application runs, then you will be informed of the missing DLL (if it is missing).  Right now, your app is being built with the assumption that an import library is used to specify the missing functions.  You have to add the import library to your linker settings.

Comment: I linked with libmgl.dll.a and wrote -static flag. It compiles and runs, but requires libmgl.dll and all MinGW libs. I've got that there is no static libs of mathgl for me, but can i link all mingw stuff as static libs?